# add recaptcha just doesn't work

Tags: recaptcha

i would like to add a recaptcha to my web form and have been following the instructions on the web but i just can't get the image to display.
i followed these steps:
- downloaded and unzipped the recaptcha folder
- uploaded recaptchalib onto my root folder (server side)
- made an account on recaptcha site
- copied the public and private key to paste into my php code
- i pasted the php code into my html code like this:

```
<form method="post" name="contact_form" action="contactengine.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="Name">Name </label>
</td>
<td>
<input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" maxlength="300" value=""/ >
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="Email">Email </label>
</td>
<td>                                                                                    
<input id="Email" name="Email" type="text" maxlength="300" value=""/ >
</td>
</tr>
<td class="buttons">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="" />
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php'); // reCAPTCHA Library
$pubkey = "public-key-here"; // Public API Key
echo recaptcha_get_html($pubkey); // Display reCAPTCHA
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

this should at least display the recaptcha image, but i just cannot get it to display.
i tried making an index.php and pasting my  in there, but that doesn't even display a thing.

It should be so simple and yet i must be missing something. It's driving me crazy.
Help will be much appreciated, thanks

B

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any PHP errors in the log? Check to see if you are able to open a socket. The reCaptcha library must be able to do a fetch server side.

If you can't then enable sockets by adding "allow_url_fopen=On" to your php.ini config file.